# why is the Haar cascade mouth detection not working?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to use the haarcascade classifiers the face work just fine but the mouth is not working the multiscale function is not working I've searched the net and tried all solutions that say's the path to the classifier is not right, but still not working. can anyone help me with this

```py
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(
    r"C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
mouthCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(
    r"C:\Program Files\opencv-master\data\mouth.xml")
# Read the image
image = cv2.imread(
    r"C:\Users\hp\Desktop\lip reading dataset\faces\face_18.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('img', gray)
cv2.waitKey()
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
# Draw a rectangle around the faces
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    roi_color = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    cv2.imshow('gray', roi_gray)
    cv2.waitKey()
    mouth = mouthCascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in mouth:
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex + ew, ey + eh), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow("Mouth found", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: yes that was just to make sure its reading the image properly even when I remove it still not working the Multiscale function of the mouth @GustavoKaneto

Comment: if you provide the source files, others can test your code directly...

Comment: the code worked here.

Comment: than the problem is in the referencing to the mouth cascade but I can't fix it I tried every possible solution for the referencing method  still giving me this error cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::dete @GustavoKaneto